# hook_url_outbound_alter() not working

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to rewrite the URL of a node. I have the following test code:

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {

    if ($path == 'testpage') {
        $path = 'test-alias';
        $options['alias'] = $path;
    }
}
```

Which doesn't seem to do anything when I visit /testpage or /test-alias. It's definitely executing the code inside the if statement. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have previously implemented hook_url_inbound_alter(), which works perfectly and doesn't do anything on this particular page. I also use the Path module.

Comment: Are you sure you are understanding the use of outbound url alters?  Unless I am being dense this morning (totally possible) outbound alters changes urls that drupal creates, eg, via its url() function, that are then subsequently embedded in html/pages/etc.  Thus it wouldn't do anything if you actually typed in a url into your browser.

Comment: It is very likely I am using it wrong. As I understand it, I can use outbound_alter to create an alias for a given path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create an alias using [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7), you need to implement also [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7), since the former is for links output from Drupal, and the latter is for links received from Drupal. The former changes the path with its alias, while the latter changes the alias with the equivalent path.

Keep in mind that:

- If you are not doing conditional replacements, then it is probably less performance-heavy to use the normal Drupal path aliases
- Between the arguments taken from `hook_url_outbound_alter()`, `$path` is the path as already changed by the previously executed module, while `$original_path` is the path before being changed from any module

Also, `$options['alias']` is really a boolean, not a string, which tells `url()` whenever the path being passed to the function is already a path alias. In the case it is, [`drupal_get_path_alias()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) will not be called.

Comment: I have it working now with `hook_url_inbound_alter() { if ($path == 'test-alias') { $path = 'node/1234';}`. I'm still not entirely sure how it works though... I also can't find information on `$options` anywhere - my ultimate goal is to rewrite queries. I accepted your answer as it does solve the particular question I asked.

Comment: `$options` is the same argument taken from `url()`.